# What would happen if we had a different kind of metal in our bloodstream?

Tags: biochemistry, chemical-biology

It is a common fact that we have iron in our blood. But what if we had something different in its place? Like instead of iron what if it was copper, or silver, or what if we had gold in our blood stream instead? Theoretically, what would that do?

Comment: If we would use copper to transport oxygen in the blood, we would be more closely related to [horseshoe crabs](https://www.iflscience.com/plants-and-animals/how-horseshoe-crab-blood-saves-millions-lives/).

Comment: Iron in blood is a part of heme group in [haemoglobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin). [Heme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heme#Major_hemes) is a complex molecule with a [porphyrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyrin) ring attached to a iron center. Several other such molecules with similar structures are also there, [Chlorophyll a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_a) has a similar structure with **Magnesium** at the centre of the Porphyrin ring. 
Researching on chlorophyll a will give you an idea.

Comment: Instead of one Fe(II) atom like in our heme, the carrier hemocyanin in horseshoe crabs has two bound copper ions to bind to a single dioxygen.

Comment: The whole biological system of a human is finely tuned. You can't just willy-nilly substitute some other metal for iron in hemoglobin.

Comment: Assuming that you could construct a recombinant protein that was not rejected by the immune system, and used some metal other than iron in its oxygen-binding cofactor, it makes for an interesting if bizarre question. Afaik release of oxygen is passive (ie does not require another protein, even if it's complex) so if you tuned the protein's $CO_2$ and oxygen binding constants just right, why well, I don't know, it might just work. Question is, why don't we have a copper-loaded oxygen carrier? Just because?

Comment: A better way to ask this question would be not to assume we could replace iron with something else in *our* biology but to ask whether alternative systems for carrying oxygen are possible and what the implications would be. Our blood is fine-tuned to use iron, but alternatives are possible.

Comment: Don't ask me about the crabs but Cu will be surely toxic somewhere else in our organism. I like the answer by PJR.

Comment: This is an interesting question, it is a pity that it is closed. Students in the future will need to tackle questions such as this so they could benefit from some thoughtful answers from people with some knowledge of the area.

Answer (score 3):

To start, transition metal complexes with large porphyrin-like molecules are so electronically complex that standard chemical intuition doesn't apply and you have to either do the experiment or run a (nearly impossible) calculation to determine what effect a non-physiological metal would have on the protein activities. In the case of hemoglobin, your best bet would be to think about metals which have two accessible oxidation states because the interconversion of Fe(II) and Fe(III) is critical to the function of hemoglobin.

To give a broader answer, let's think about the general question of substituting non-native metals into a protein. This is, in fact, an very interesting and open question. On smaller metalloproteins there have been studies probing whether nature 'picked' the best metal for a task or just a convenient/abundant one [1,2]. The focus of those studies is on catalysis, and there are cases where many non-physiological metals can function in the protein and even catalyze the reaction as good or even better than the wild type.

[1] https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ar500227u

[2] https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpcb.6b00997